# Send a 0 byte using DataOutputStream?

Tags: java, sockets, dataoutputstream

I'm creating an server for an existing client. This client reads input from server using a socket and DataInputStream. It checks for end of server message using:

```
byte c = in.readByte();
if( c == 0) { //the end.
```

On the server i'm using a serversocket and DataOutputStream to send message to client:

```
out.write(bytes[])
```

How can i send a 0 byte so that the client knows it is the end of the message?

Comment: a `DataOutputStream` does have a method called `writeByte`. Why don't you just use that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surely you just want an array of length 1, with the single element set to 0 ?

```
out.write(new byte[]{0});
```

Comment: Didn't think it would be this simple, a simple and working answer. Thumbs up!